# Finding a string value after using a regex match - javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

So I'm quite new to regex and I'm trying to get my head around this problem, after a while of trying to figure it out myself I can't really think of what to do. :)

So far this is what I have.

```
    fullText = lines.join(" ").replace(/\s+/g, " "); // Gets all the string values

    // Wait for game
    gameSignalMsg = new RegExp(StarterConfig.JoinGameMsg, "g"); // Find the game signal
    gameSignal = fullText.match(gameSignalMsg); // Found a game signal

    if (gameSignal) {
        print(gameSignal);
    }
```

It finds gameSignal no problems, but the issue I have is that there is ALWAYS another random string value after the gameSignal that I want to fetch. I have no idea how I would also find that extra random string value.

Thanks guys.

More info:

It's usually just something like: full text = "There are 2332 users browsing etc etc." + StartConfig.JoinGameMsg + "randomstring" It finds StartConfig.JoinGameMsg, I just also want to assign the randomstring that comes after it to a variable. Sorry if this isn't what you guys mean.

The string that I want to catch is a combination of letters + numbers

Comment: What is `StarterConfig.JoinGameMsg`? What is your input? What do you mean by "random string value", specifically?

Comment: I'm not really sure how I'd explain it but here goes.

StarterConfig.JoinGameMsg is just a variable that I set myself, it's the string that signals there is about to be a random string that I want to store. Basically I input StarterConfig.JoinMsg + "aa1", aa1 for example is the random string that I want to catch and store.

Hope that is more clear

Comment: Please show an example of you input and what you want to do with it (for example "I'm dealing with strings like `"joining-game:aarandom"` and I want to grab `aarandom` which is the random part, it can contain letters and numbers")

Comment: It's usually just something like:

full text = "There are 2332 users browsing etc etc." + StartConfig.JoinGameMsg + "randomstring"

It finds StartConfig.JoinGameMsg, I just also want to assign the randomstring that comes after it to a variable. Sorry if this isn't what you guys mean.

Comment: Ok, that's clearer. Edit your question to add these information (don't answer only in the comments) and you're good to go!

Comment: what is your random string made up of ? letters , numbers? special characters any delimiters

Comment: Thanks.

aelor, letters + numbers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can change your line to :

```
gameSignalMsg = new RegExp(StarterConfig.JoinGameMsg+" \\w+", "g");
```

this should make the random string matched too along with the variable you have supplied , note the space I have given in the beginning. its just there to say that the random string is after the first space given after the variable.

like:

```
StarterConfig.JoinGameMsg randomstring
```

or

```
StarterConfig.JoinGameMsg abc123 notthis
```

or

```
StarterConfig.JoinGameMsg helloworld
```